# Sql question where age is stored in integer but at output we want it as a varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose we have Employee table as Empid,empname,age and data stored as (1001,'Ana',25),(1002,'Smith',34)...

The output should look like :
Empid  empname     Age
1001    Ana      25 years old
1002   Smith     34 years old
...

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(Employee.Empid,' ',Employee.Empname,' ', Employee.Age,' years old')
```

This would return a varchar value for every row, containing the information since concat() automatically converts numerics to its equivalent nonbinary string form.